# iPhone NSTimer change repeat time

Tags: iphone

I have a static method in which I setup NSTimer, but sometimes I need to change repeat time. How to do that if I work with static method? Should be something like this:

```
+ (void)setupTimer:(BOOL)updateTime newTime:(int)time {
     NSTimer *timer;
     if (updateTime) {
         [timer invalidate];
         timer = nil;
     }
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(myMethod:)
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];
}
```

But it's not working...and I know that I cannot invalidate in this case my timer...but also I cannot use NSTimer declared as member of class in static method...How to be ? thanks....

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems that you're not keeping a reference to `timer` anywhere, so `[timer invalidate]` will always fail because it's always a call of `[nil invalidate]` in your code.

Comment: I know, but where to keep reference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prefix the variable with `static`.

```
static NSTimer *timer;
```

If you overwrite the timer variable, you should invalidate it first, because otherwise you'll have a timer running, that you don't have access to anymore.

Comment: Yep, but I don't want to keep static variable...It's bad solution...Looking for something better...

Comment: @Jim Why is a static variable a bad solution?

Comment: Trying to add prefix, but have another error "expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'static'" What is that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to write this without static functions but you can also do this using static functions. If there should be only one instance of that class then use a singleton-pattern.

for doing this with static functions then just use

```
static NSTimer *timer
```

<strike>but you also have to retain your new and also release the old timer because the function `scheduledTimer...` allocs an `NSTimer`instance but also autoreleases it. If dont retain that timer then the timer will be deallocated later and will afaik not call your method.</strike>

Comment: The run loop retains the timer until it's invalidated.